# module scipy has no attribute __version__

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda, librosa

I am using Anaconda (Spyder)
I am trying to importing some libraries as shown
(librosa , keras , .....)
I was getting this error when importing librosa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.ndimage'
then I wrote this command in Anaconda prompt  (conda install scipy) to reinstall scipy
now I get this error
AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute '**version**'
I tried to figure out how to solve but i couldn't ,
any one can help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK9m3.png)

Here is the code

```
import os
import scipy
import librosa 
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Dense , Dropout , Flatten , Conv1D , Input , MaxPooling1D
from keras.model import Model
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping , ModelCheckpoint
from keras import backend as K
from metplotlib import pyplot
from sklearn.preprocessing import LableEncoder
```

Edit :
I notice that : When I use anaconda prompt no error occur while importing librosa but when I use spyder , the error occur

**Problem Solved**
Thanks all
Problem solved by updating spyder using this command in Anaconda prompt

```
conda update spyder
```

Comment: If you named a file `scipy.py` or named a folder `scipy`, pick a different name.

Comment: I didn't name any file or folder like that

Comment: try to install `scipy` using the Spyder prompt by typing `!pip install scipy` then try to check the version again.